# In my LI, why is the bg color of the overflow different than the bg color of the rest?

Tags: html, css, scroll

I'm showing code in an ordered list, so that it displays with line numbers. Each `li` has a `pre` tag filled with a line of code in it.

My problem is that when I set the width of the `ol`, and I allow the overflow to scroll, the background color of the overflow is different than the background color of the area originally showing.

The background of the `ol` has to be a different color than the background of the `li`s to make the line numbers stand out.

Is there something wrong with my CSS, why is this happening? How can I have scrolling, and different background colors for line numbers and code?

HTML:

```
<ol class="code">
  <li>
    <pre>Hello World! This is a long line that you have to scroll to see.</pre>
  </li>
  <li>
    <pre>This is the second line that you have to scroll to see.</pre>
  </li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
  ol {
    width:200px;
    background-color:#CFCFCF; }

  pre {
    color:#FFF;
    background-color:#000; }

  .code {
    overflow:scroll; }
```

**[Example page](http://jsbin.com/itiki5/2)**

The problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct behaviour. This is because when text overflows out of an element (in this case, the `pre`) the box does *not* grow with it.

Answer (score 1):

To get around this width problem, you can set your `pre` tag to `display: inline`. Then, I simply added some extra padding on the `li` tag to retain the same look.

Full example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        ol
        {
            width: 200px;
            background-color: #CFCFCF;
        }
        pre
        {
            color: #FFF;
            background-color: #000;
            display: inline;
        }
        .code li
        {
            margin: 12px 0px 12px 0px;
        }
        .code
        {
            overflow: scroll;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ol class="code">
        <li>
            <pre>World! This is a long line that you have to scroll to see.</pre>
        </li>
        <li>
            <pre>This is the second line that you have to scroll to see.</pre>
        </li>
    </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced a similar problem using Google Prettify Syntax Highlighter with line numbers, alternate row coloring and allowing overflow scrollbars when exceeding specified length or width. For my case I solved it with inline-block.

```
<body>
<code style="display:block;width:100px;overflow:scroll;">
    <!-- Solution: add inline-block style to ordered list so that background-color will not be cropped -->
    <ol style="display:inline-block;">
        <li style="background-color:yellow;">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</li>
        <li>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</li>
        <li style="background-color:yellow;">ccccccccccccccc</li>
    </ol>
</code> 
</body>
```